# How do I get tab completion in ipython in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I installed ipython with pip --user and python-mode via the package manager in emacs 24. I am able to send code to and launch ipython from a python file after having added this to my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode-6.1.3")
(require 'python-mode)
(setq-default py-shell-name "~/.local/bin/ipython")
```

but it doesn't seem to do tab completion. When I type `C-h b` to see key-bindings I can see one called "py-shell-complete" with binding "" but when I do "M-tab" it alt-tabs to another window (in my case, chrome browser). Is that the ipython completion key im looking for in the first place? And, if it is, how do I get it to work off just the tab key?

Comment: FWIW `TAB` *should* work out of the box for this case with Emacs-24.4 and no extra package installed (i.e. using python.el rather than python-mode.el).

Answer (score 0):

It's just TAB - completes at the end of string, otherwise calls indent.

In case it doesn't work, please file a bug-report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode